# Como puedo realizar una barra de progreso para el iframe de youtube personalizada mediante un div y no un input range?

Tags: youtube-api

Mi caso consiste en que al hacer una barra de progreso con un div (aunque con un input surge el mismo problema), tengo que utilizar un setInterval() para que cada tiempo determinado la barra se actualice. Al hacer esto surgen algunos fallos en los que al cambiar el minuto del video con la barra personalizada se queda medio pillada por el uso del setInterval.

Entonces la pregunta es: como se haria con esta API (youtube-API, https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es#Functions) una barra de progreso personalizada tan funcional como la de youtube misma en la que la barra avanza tan suavemente junto al video sin el uso de un setInterval?

```
//html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <title>doc</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="video">
      <div id="player" class="player"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
      <div class="test">

      </div>
      <div class="bar-box">
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="bc">
            <div class="bcc">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </body>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="Jv.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>

//javascript
let player;
let videoId;
let rank = document.getElementById('YouTube-player-progress');
let ranv = document.getElementById('YouTube-player-volume');
const video = document.querySelector('.video')

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  console.log('api is loaded');

  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: 'OqvQZnNxPx8',
    playerVars: {
      playersinline: 1,
      autoplay: 0,
      controls: 1,
      rel: 0,
      disablekb: 1
    },
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
    }
  })
}

function youTubePlayerCurrentTimeChange(currentTime) {
  player.currentTimeSliding = false;
  player.seekTo((currentTime * player.getDuration()) / 100, true);
}

function youTubePlayerCurrentTimeSlide() {
  player.currentTimeSliding = true;
}

var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    done = true;
  }
}

//play/pause

function onPlayerReady() {
  console.log("ready");

};


function pauseVideo() {
  player.pauseVideo()
}

function playVideo() {
player.playVideo();
}



let bar = document.querySelector('.bar');
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.bc');
let progressDot = document.querySelector('.bcc');
const barw = bar.offsetWidth;







// 20

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const progressBar = document.querySelector('.bc');
  const bar = document.querySelector('.bar');
  const barWidth = progressBar.parentElement.offsetWidth;



  bar.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    let pbr = event.offsetX;
    progressBar.style.width = `calc(${pbr}px)`;
    progressDot.style.left = `calc(${pbr}px - 7.5px)`;
    video.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  });

  bar.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
      video.style.pointerEvents = "none";
      wtf = 'xdnt';
    function onMouseMove(event) {
      let cBar = window.innerWidth - bar.offsetWidth;
      let ccBar= event.clientX - cBar/2;
      progressBar.style.width = `${ccBar}px`;
      let pal = progressBar.offsetWidth;
      progressDot.style.left = `calc(${ccBar}px - 7.5px)`;

    }


    function onMouseUp(event) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
      video.style.pointerEvents = "all";
      let cBar = window.innerWidth - bar.offsetWidth;
      let ccBar= event.clientX - cBar/2;
      let pbar = (ccBar/barw)*100;
      player.seekTo(pbar*player.getDuration()/100);
      wtf = 'xd';
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

  });
});


let wtf = 'xd';
bar.onmousedown = () => {

  console.log('on');
}

document.body.onmouseup = () => {

  console.log('off');
}


setInterval(() => {
  if(wtf === 'xd') {
    handleProgress();
  }
},100)



function handleProgress() {

  if(wtf === 'xd') {
    function lol() {
      let barDuration = player.getDuration();
      let barCurrentT = player.getCurrentTime();
      let porcentaje = (barCurrentT/barDuration)*100;
      let barr = progressBar.offsetWidth;
      progressBar.style.width = `${porcentaje}%`;
      progressDot.style.left = `calc(${barr}px - 7.5px)`
    }
    lol();
  }else {
    console.log('fallo');
  }

}


//css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: red;

}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 1,
  'wght' 400,
  'GRAD' 200,
  'opsz' 48
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 38px);
  z-index: 100;

}

.player {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 38px);
  margin-bottom: -3.515624880799px;

}

.controls {
  background: #191919;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar-box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  z-index: 1;
}

.bar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111111;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.bc {
  background: #EA2027;
  height: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  min-width: 2.5px;
}


.bcc {
  background: #dfe6e9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  left: ;
  position: absolute;
}

.test {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  left: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: gracias. ya lo he hecho

Comment: Me parece que en **handleProgress**, la llamada **lol();** estaría sobrando..